# Multiple errors when trying to import mysql.connector by using a python client in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying (inside Jupyter notebook) to connect mysql database using a Python client.

inside a jupyter notebook, I type the following code:

```
import mysql.connector as connector

connection=connector.connect(user="your_username", 
                             password="your_password")
```

I then receive a massive error message as shown in the attached pictures.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here, and what is more strange is that 3 weeks ago, I wrote the exact same code, and it worked perfectly.

[image]
[image]

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter, and the mysql-connector API.
I've tried searching around the web to find someone else who had the same issue, but it seems like no one has had this issue in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: 0) Is the username and password *definitely* correct? 1) Is the MySQL server instance actually on your PC, or is it on a remote PC?  2) If on your PC, is the service running? 3) Is the MySQL server actually running on port 3306?

Comment: 4) Does your firewall allow traffic through port 3306?

Comment: [Search with many other related questions.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+%2B+target+machine+actively+refused+it&kp=1&ia=web)

Comment: 0) yes 1)it is on my pc. 2)I believe so 3)I'm unsure, but when i pass in port=3306 as a parameter, I still get the same errors 4)yes, the firewall is not an issue.